# Which should be capitalized | Resume

Tags: capitalization, lists

I'm wondering if the words in this list which describe my university coursework should all be capitalized, or just the first word? If its relevant, these are NOT the actual name of the courses. But since I brought it up, what if they were the actual name of the course?

Ex.

Relevant Coursework: Machine Learning, Database Management Systems, Data Mining, Mergers, Financial Recapitalization, Leveraged Buyouts

Comment: As this isn't an actual sentence, there's no reason it should follow English rules for sentence capitalization. Just make sure that your choice for adding capitals is consistent throughout the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the current list is not composed of official course names, they would not be capitalized.  Generally, you would capitalize a proper noun (in this case, the official names of the classes), whereas here you are listing common nouns (the subjects of your coursework).

Correct version of current example:

> Relevant coursework: machine learning, database management systems,
>   data mining, mergers, financial recapitalization, leveraged buyouts

You can read a bit more about proper and common nouns here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun#Common_and_proper_nouns

Though there are plenty of sites explaining them if you just use Google (<--- its capitalized because its proper noun).

Answer (score 1):

You should look in the university's list of courses and use whatever you find there. They're the only ones who get to decide what their courses' names are. If you are merely describing things you studied, these are not capitalized at all.

Course titles are capitalized, but areas of study are not.

Comment: But that answers only 1 of my questions. What about the current list which I have posted?

Comment: I'm not asking about titles of courses, I'm asking about the words in the list I provided. I guess either you didn't fully read my question, or you didn't understand my question. Thank you for trying to help me either way.